# Unable to overlay an image icon on a HTML paragraph displayed on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to insert an Image on a HTML page on mouse button click. This image indicates a tag to open a sticky note. I am able to figure out how to insert an image at the mouse curse location. However, I am not sure if an image can be inserted anywhere on a HTML page. Can we overlay this image on the paragraph? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.overlay_img {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
}

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).append($('<img/>', {
                      className: 'overlay_img'
                      style: 'left: '+ e.pageX +'px; top: '+ e.pageY +'px',
                      src: 'SOMETHING',
                      alt: 'SOMETHING'
                   })
                );
});
```

you can also use:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).append('<img src="" class="something" alt="some" style="left: '+ e.pageX +'px; top: '+ e.pageY +'px"/>');
});
```

For example, I append the image to `body`, you can append it to any target.

Comment: @thecodeparadox Are there any perfomance issues with the two version? I once read an article, that `$('<tagname attr="value">')` is faster than `$('<tagname>).attr('attr', 'value')`. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: @thecodeparadox I mean the performance of the code in the browser. On http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 it says that browsers own `innerHTML` function may be used. Could it be the same with the first alternative?

Comment: @thecodeparadox No they won't. I programmed a test on jsfiddle. Version one is approx. 4 times slower with my Chrome browser http://jsfiddle.net/QMFAr/ (Result is printed on console)